# Root is not allowed to grant privileges on a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, root

I have a MySQL database and I am not able to grant permissions to users on newly created databases when logging in as root.

```
mysql> create database test1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> grant usage on *.* to 'test'@'%' identified by 'test';
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)
mysql> show grants for root;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@%                                                                                            |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*hash_is_here' |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> select user();
+-----------------+
| user()          |
+-----------------+
| root@172.17.0.4 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

So as you can see, I can log in as root, root has all privileges on *.*. Any ideas how could this happen? I haven't upgraded MySQL while keeping the data (I know that this could be caused by upgrading from 5 to 5.5). Thanks.

Comment: i don't think the problem is this, but anyway, your grant command is wrong, "grant usage on *.* to 'test'@'%' identified by 'test';" like that you give all privilegies to test on all databases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have all privileges for ***root@%*** but not the "grant option".
In my MySQL installation, where my root account can apply grant, this is the output of "show grants" :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*some_hash' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

In MySQL, giving "***all privileges***" does not include grant. It must be given explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out just could not answer my own question. Root@% does not have grant, just root@localhost. https://github.com/orchardup/docker-mysql/commit/0a8dd7d85e745b26aa9793e53b92550ad968ca7d#commitcomment-5664813

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD ‘tset123123’ WITH GRANT OPTION;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD ‘tset123123’ WITH GRANT OPTION' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're not on 5.5, maybe you still need to run mysql_upgrade from the `/mysql/bin` directory?

[See the first answer here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484722/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-while-attempting-to-grant-privileges)